# How to get Users information on twitter API using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

I am currently working on a project using twitter API.

I have a code like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq; // Added for JSON Library   ( Doc)
using System.Xml;
using oAuthExample;
public partial class twitterInfo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string url = "";
    string xml = "";
    public string name = "";
    public string username = "";
    public string profileImage = "";
    public string followersCount = "";
    public string noOfTweets = "";
    public string recentTweet = "";

    //Source    http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/add-twitter-login-authentication-to.html

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetUserDetailsFromTwitter();
    }
    private void GetUserDetailsFromTwitter()
    {
        if (Request["oauth_token"] != null & Request["oauth_verifier"] != null)
        {
            imgTwitter.Visible = false;
            tbleTwitInfo.Visible = true;
            var oAuth = new oAuthTwitter();
            //Get the access token and secret.
            oAuth.AccessTokenGet(Request["oauth_token"], Request["oauth_verifier"]);
            if (oAuth.TokenSecret.Length > 0)
            {
               url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json";
               xml = oAuth.oAuthWebRequest(oAuthTwitter.Method.GET, url, String.Empty);

             JObject o = JObject.Parse(xml);
             name = Convert.ToString(o["name"]);
             username = Convert.ToString(o["screen_name"]);
             profileImage = Convert.ToString(o["profile_image_url"]);
             followersCount = Convert.ToString(o["followers_count"]);
             noOfTweets = Convert.ToString(o["statuses_count"]);
             noOfTweets = Convert.ToString(o["birthday"]);

            }
        }
    }
    protected void imgTwitter_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var oAuth = new oAuthTwitter();
        if (Request["oauth_token"] == null)
        {
            //Redirect the user to Twitter for authorization.
            //Using oauth_callback for local testing.

                        // R_ use the dynamic url director
            // Call back URL to direct the user to the page
            oAuth.CallBackUrl = "http://localhost:518/Account/TwitterInfo.aspx";

            Response.Redirect(oAuth.AuthorizationLinkGet());
        }
        else
        {
            GetUserDetailsFromTwitter();
        }
    }
}
```

This code is part of a Twitter API project to return (name, twitterusername, profileimage,followers and number of tweets).
I know that Twitter API does not retrieve users email address.
but I want to retrieve user's profile ID and user's profile link...
Can Anyone tell me what should I have to change from the code above to retrieve those two datas?

Here's [a link](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/add-twitter-login-authentication-to.html)  for the complete source code.

Answer (score 3):

The code you're using for account/verify_credentials looks okay and if that's working, you can use the same code, but change the URL. The account/verify_credentials will work for the authenticated user, but you'll have to use [users/show](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show) for specifying any user. There's an [account/settings](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/account/settings) endpoint, but again that's only for the authenticated user.

Only the individual user can see their own settings page. You can send the user to https://twitter.com/settings/account, which is their own profile page, but they'll need to be logged in to see it. I don't know if this will meet your requirements, but one of the things you can do is identify an individual's public twitter page, like this:

```
string publicTwitterPage = "https://twitter.com/" + username;
```

Comment: On the field guide, they have definitions for each field in a response. In the case of a user object, https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/users, it's "id".